# Decomposition of a random vector into a linear sum of bounded random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, linear-transformations, geometric-probability

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n\times m}$, where $n<m$ and rank($A$)=n. Define a set (a zonotope) $\mathcal{C}(A)=\{\bf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n|\bf{y}=A\bf{x},\bf{x} \in [-1,1]^m\}$.

Consider a random vector $\bf{Y}$ whose support is $\text{supp}{\bf{Y}}=\mathcal{C}(A)$, and expectation $\mathsf{E}[{\bf{Y}}]=A\bf{s}$, where $\bf{s}$ is a constant vector.

**My question** : How to find a sufficient condition on the distribution of $\bf{Y}$ such that $\bf{Y}$ can be decomposed as a sum of $m$ random variables, i.e., ${\bf{Y}} = \sum_{i=1}^m{{\bf{a}}}_iX_i$,
where
random vector ${\bf{X}}=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m)$ satisfies

(i) $A{\bf{X}}$ follows the same distribution as ${\bf{Y}}$; (ii) $\text{supp}X_i \subset [-1,1]$; and (iii) expectation $\mathsf{E}[{\bf{X}}]=\bf{s}$.

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Some initial observation: given a realization $\bf{y}$, and its inverse image is just the set $\mathcal{I}({\bf{y}})=\{{\bf{x}}|A{\bf{x}}=\bf{y}, {\bf{x}} \in [-1,1]^m \}$. For any ${\bf{x}} \in \mathcal{I}({\bf{y}})$, by  range-null space theorem, we can decompose it as ${\bf{x}}={\bf{x}}_r+{\bf{x}}_n$, where ${\bf{x}}_r$ is a specific solution (e.g. we can let ${\bf{x}}_r=A^\dagger\bf{y}$), and ${\bf{x}}_n$ in null space.  We further denote the nullspace of $A$ by a basis $\{\sum_{i=1}^{m-n}\alpha_i {\bf{b}}_i, \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and then we can equivalently denote $\mathcal{I}({\bf{y}})=\{A^\dagger\bf{y}+\sum_{i=1}^{m-n}\alpha_i {\bf{b}}_i\}\cap[-1,1]^m$.

When $n=m-1$, we can simply write $\mathcal{I}({\bf{y}})= \{A^\dagger\bf{y}+\alpha_1{\bf{b}}_1, \alpha_1 \in [\alpha_\ell,\alpha_u]\}$, where $\alpha_\ell, \alpha_u$ are lower and upper bound of $\alpha_1$ to make sure $\forall \bf{x} \in \mathcal{I}(\bf{y})$, we have $$\bf{x}=A^\dagger\bf{y}+\alpha_1{\bf{b}}_1 \in [A^\dagger\bf{y}+\alpha_\ell{\bf{b}}_1,A^\dagger\bf{y}+\alpha_u{\bf{b}}_1] \subset [-1,1]^m,$$ and they only depend on $\bf{y}$.

In this case a sufficient condition of $\bf{Y}$ such that there exists a random vector $\bf{X}$ satisfying (i)(ii)(iii) is $$-\boldsymbol{1}^m \preceq \mathsf{E}[A^\dagger\bf{Y}+\alpha_\ell({\bf{Y}}){\bf{b}}_1] \preceq \mathsf{E}[\bf{X}]={\bf{s}} \preceq \mathsf{E}[A^\dagger\bf{Y}+\alpha_u({\bf{Y}}){\bf{b}}_1] \preceq \boldsymbol{1}^m.$$

But this method seems difficult to extend to the case when $1\leq n <m-1$. How to find a similar sufficient condition of $\bf{Y}$? The difficulty is the dimension of nullspace is not one anymore, and describing $\mathcal{I}({\bf{y}})$ becomes difficult.